# intellij subfolders structure

Tags: intellij-idea, package

This topic/issue is easy, but so far I haven´t found the right way to make it work and that takes me a lot of time, dealing with the creation of subfolders.

Let´s take this example

I created a folder under resources called META-INFO:

[image]

When I create a subfolder I would like to have this structure

```
resources
 -META-INFO
  -newfolder
```

But this is what in reality happens

[image]

This also often happens in my main folder, when creating packages
Instead of having this:

```
com.myproject.demo
  -model
```

Does this

```
com.myproject.demo.model
```

Is there a missing configuration? I looked at similar topics, but I couldn´t find the solution. As well I looked at videos, but no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's just showing it that way. The real folder structure is like you want it. Add a file to `com.myproject` and it will split the `demo` folder from `com.myproject.demo`

Answer (score 1):

The folder is treated as part of a package thus the .-notation.

If you disable the option "Flatten packages"  you will get the tree structure to show instead. However the directory structure is still proper. 
Also you can switch to "Project Files"-view rather than "Project" to see it as directories.

This should be the relevant documentation as well:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html

Answer (score 1):

just uncheck the option "Hide Empty Middle Package" from the project drop down menu (wheel like drop down menu on the top)

Answer (score 0):

Frist of all, I click thi the three vertical dots icon.

Then I Click to Flatten Packages.

[setting-packges-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22M0Q.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).